# Do I need a DHCP in an internal network?

Tags: networking, configuration, ip, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Hi and ty for your reading,

I'm a beginner in virtualization and as part of a project I have to configure the IPs of a physical server and 3 virtual machines on Hyper-V in an internal network.

My question is, do I need to have a DHCP because I don't want to have a particular domain?
Which IPs and gateways do you advise me to use, considering my number of machines ?

Mattéo

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subnet like 192.168.99.x with a mask of 255.255.255.0.
Enter your IP manually and you won't need a DHCP.